# oracle query to fetch count

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with organisation names and approval_status. Approval_status can be either approved /rejected. How do I fetch count of approved and rejected records for each organisation using oracle SQL query and PLSQL procedure

Comment: What are your expected results?  Both options below work, they just output the results differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*For Oracle's SQL Select statement, One option would be using `sum` of `decoded` columns as below :*

```
select organisation_name, 
       sum(decode(approval_status,'approved',1,0)) as "Count(Approved)",
       sum(decode(approval_status,'rejected',1,0)) as "Count(Rejected)"
  from tab
 group by organisation_name;
```

*You can create a Stored Procedure returning these calculated values as results as :*

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> create or replace procedure pr_get_org_count( 
                                             i_org_name tab.organisation_name%type,
                                             o_cnt_approved out pls_integer,
                                             o_cnt_rejected out pls_integer,
                                            ) is

begin
     select sum(decode(approval_status,'approved',1,0)) ,
            sum(decode(approval_status,'rejected',1,0))
       into o_cnt_approved, o_cnt_rejected
       from tab
      where organisation_name = i_org_name;

    dbms_output.put_line(' Approved Count is : '||o_cnt_approved);
    dbms_output.put_line(' Rejected Count is : '||o_cnt_rejected);
    -- these previous two line can be used to show the results through command line.
end;
```

If you need to output multi-rows for each organisation, use the above-most grouped select statement within a cursor inside our procedure without parameters as :

```
SQL> create or replace procedure pr_get_org_count is    
begin
    for c in
    (  
     select organisation_name,
            sum(decode(approval_status,'approved',1,0)) as cnt_approved ,
            sum(decode(approval_status,'rejected',1,0)) as cnt_rejected
       from tab
      group by organisation_name
    )
    loop
      dbms_output.put(' Organisation Name : '||c.organisation_name);        
      dbms_output.put(' [ Approved Count : '||c.cnt_approved);
      dbms_output.put_line(' - Rejected Count : '||c.cnt_rejected||' ]');
    end loop;
end;
```

***EDIT*** *(related to the comment)*
*You can convert this procedure to the style below to mail the results :*

```
create or replace procedure pr_get_org_count( 
                                             i_org_name tab.organisation_name%type,
                                             o_cnt_approved out pls_integer,
                                             o_cnt_rejected out pls_integer,
                                            ) is
  v_path  varchar2(4000):='http://www.mycompany.com.tr/main/default.aspx?email=';
  v_email varchar2(4000):='barbaros.ozhan@mycompany.com.tr';
  v_text  varchar2(4000):='My Results | for Approved : ';
  v_url   varchar2(4000);
  v_rep   varchar2(4000);
begin
  select sum(decode(approval_status,'approved',1,0)) ,
         sum(decode(approval_status,'rejected',1,0))
    into o_cnt_approved, o_cnt_rejected
    from tab
   where organisation_name = i_org_name;

   v_text := v_text||to_char(o_cnt_approved)||' - for Rejected : '||to_char(o_cnt_rejected);
   v_url  := v_path||'?email='||v_email||'&email_text='||v_text;
   v_rep  := utl_http.request(utl_url.escape(v_url, false, 'UTF-8'));
end;
```

Comment: Hi, Yes that helps... I want to send this o/p as a report over email to some email id's. In the same stored procedure can I do that..

Comment: for the first stored procedure... i am executing this in TOAD .. please help me understand how i can display the output in a table kind format

Comment: this gives o/p in a one liner... There are multiple organisations. For each organisation I would need the Approved records and rejected records count respectively. In a table format. The headers should be ORG_NAME    APPROVED    REJECTED ... below this each org name should display with respective counts. I am unable to give you a picture to show the o/p format. Hope u got my point. And many thanks for helping me learn this concepts

Comment: @newlearner exactly, that's another option to output multi-organization which needs a cursor as you've said.

Comment: Now if I want to display it in a tabular format like how we have data in an excel sheet. i want to have a table created with borders and 3 columns -- ORG_NAME, APPROVED, REJECTED. These should be the columns and as per the number of rows returned I want to have rows below each. Is that possible and This table format should go as body in an email to few people.

Comment: @newlearner you're welcome. There's a nice utility of Tom Kyte, who's a famous Oracle man, called `owa_sylk`. Try to search and wrap the content into a stored db package. I already mentioned about email subject above, but never tried to email by using `owa_sylk` package, perhaps it would be such a nice exercise for you. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using `conditional aggregation` with a `case` statement:

```
select organisation, 
       count(case when approval_status = 'approved' then 1 end) as approvedcount,
       count(case when approval_status = 'rejected' then 1 end) as rejectedcount
from yourtable
group by organisation
```

Comment: I would want to extract this as a report and send over email on a monthly basis. Can I use this query inside a PLSQL procedure. Please help with the process